# Modificar un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. En el instituto nos han dado un ejercicio de lógica donde nos piden modificar un array que viene así `["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"]` y debería salir así:

```
"********* // * Hello * // * World * // * in * // * a * //  * frame * // *********"
```

Hasta ahora he utilizado esta función pero no me ha dado el resultado esperado:

```
 function frame(arrWords){
     let wordLarge = [0]
     for (let i=0; i < arrWords.length; i++){
       if(arrWords.length > wordLarge){
         wordLarge = arrWords[i].length + 2
       }
     }
     // console.log(wordLarge);
     let arteriscoTop = "*".repeat(wordLarge)
     for (let i=0; i < arrWords.length; i++){
       console.log(`${arteriscoTop}
       ${arrWords[i]}`)
     }
   };
```

Si alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo y me pudiese guiar, lo agradecería.

Comment: Del código se infiere que la cantidad de asteriscos es variables, cosa que no se menciona en el texto, por tanto está pregunta requiere de aclaraciones

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>Ejemplo</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv="es" />
```

```
<script>
    var array=["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"];
    //esta funcion agrega al final del array un elemento    
    array.push("********");
    //con esta otra puedes agregar al inicio otro elemento
    array.splice(0,0,"// // ********");

    document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = array.join("* // *");

</script>
```

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero usando esas funciones para alterar la matriz sale la cadena que buscas.

Comment: ¿Donde está definido esto `document.getElementById("array") `? Si no tiene un elemento con esa id no funcionará.

Comment: Hola @Brea, bienvenidx, para responder una pregunta, siempre debes ofrecer un contexto comprensible para la pregunta a la que estas contribuyendo, para que tu respuesta sea mas digerible y rica en contenido, asi como acompañarse de tu mejor habilidad de redacción, mira el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y[¿Como responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), un saludo.

Comment: No se copio bien el html, soy nuevo en el foro. El id="array" lo puedes poner como atributo en una etiqueta parrafo <p id="array"></p> dentro del body de html, de esta forma funcionara el script

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esta tarea existen varios métodos que te pueden servir, mira los siguientes ejemplos:

**Ciclado y concatenación**:

Puedes ciclar y aplicar la lógica necesaria para concatenar tu string.

```js
var array = ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"];

function toFormattedString(arr) {
  var output = "*********"
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let word = " // * "+arr[i]+" *";
    output = output + word;
    if (i == arr.length -1 ) output = output + " // "
  }
  output = output + "*********"
  return output
}

console.log(toFormattedString(array)); // => ********* // * Hello * // * World * // * in * // * a * //  * frame * // *********
```

**Mapenado el array**:

Al mapear el array puedes interactuar con cada valor este y aplicar la lógica necesaria para retornar los valores modificados en un nuevo array y luego trabajarlo para convertirlo a string. Puedes usar esta opción en dado caso de que desees usar el array para otra operación antes de pasarlo a string.

```js
var array = ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"];

function mapedOutput(arr, fix) {
  var output = arr.map(o => {
    return "* " + o + " *"
  })
  return fix + " // " + output.join("//") + " // " + fix
}

console.log(mapedOutput(array, "*******"))
```

**Unshift, Push y Join** (Mas simplificado):

Opción mas simples con los métodos unshift, push y join.

```js
var array = ["Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame"];

array.push("******")
array.unshift("******")
let string = array.join(" * //  * ")

console.log(string) // => ****** * //  * Hello * //  * World * //  * in * //  * a * //  * frame * //  * ******
```

Al final la opción mas larga (*ciclado y concatenación*) es la mas segura segun mi opinion, ya que puedes aplicar mas lógica que con `map` en el mismo ciclado lo que se me hace menos tedioso al final de la tarea.

Te dejo unos links utiles para que observes los métodos y lógica aplicada:

- [Map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Unshift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)
- [Push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Loop For](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda, un saludo.